# Form and FPDF - initializing variable with $_SESSION -> why $_SESSION gets overwritten when it's null?

Tags: php, variables, null, initialization, session-variables

I've built pretty simple php form, which posts into $_SESSION and after that generates pdf from $_SESSION data. I'm using fpdf to generate the pdf. Before outputting anything via fpdf I want to check whether uploaded file $_SESSION is null (because i want to change the output then)

Everything works as is supposed to, but I'm really confused why $_SESSION data gets overwritten if session is null:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['attachments']) && !empty($_SESSION['attachments'])) {
    $attachments = $_SESSION['attachments'];
}
else {
    $attachments = "No attachments";
}
```

Now, $_SESSION['attachments'] contains a serialized paths of the attachments, but is null if no attachments are uploaded. Why this if clause initializes and overwrites the SESSION as follow:

```
var_dump($_SESSION['attachments']);
```

Output:

```
string 'No attachments' (length=14)
```

Stripped fpdf script to demonstrate what I'm doing:

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}

//Lot of other checking

if(isset($_SESSION['attachments']) && !empty($_SESSION['attachments'])) {
    $attachments = $_SESSION['attachments'];
}
else {
    $attachments = "No attachments";
}

//a lot of fpdf functions. AddMultiRow is my own function

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->AddMultiRow(utf8_decode("Required attachments:"), $attachments, 1);
$pdf->Output(//output comes here);
?>
```

Comment: have you checked that file is really uploaded or not?

Comment: And you are sure this is the only piece of code where you reference $_SESSION var ?

Comment: @BhavikShah yes I have. My file upload script doesn't set the session if no files are uploaded.

Comment: Wait, you dump `$_SESSION['attachments']` but you get the contents of the variable `$attachments`, which has been set to `'No attachments'` because either `$_SESSION['attachments']` wasn't `set` or it was `empty`...

Comment: @vodich not only part. But every other parts are just initializing new variable with the session. like for example: $file = $_SESSION['attachment'];

Comment: @Havelock yes, that's exactly what happens, and that's why I'm confused.

Comment: So, `$_SESSION['attachments']` has been set with the contents of `$attachments` somewhere... You might need to provide some more code.

Comment: @Havelock, I've tried to search all the references but found only initializations of new variables, and nothing that should initialize the session. I was thinking if this has something to do with FDPF script.

Comment: Initialising should happen only once. Value assignment however may occur multiple times on different places in the code.

Comment: There is no line, where $_SESSION['attachments'] would get a new value. Only initialising of new variables with $_SESSION value. In this scenario, $_SESSION['attachments'] doesn't even exist, its null.

Comment: I've var_dumped this session before running this fpdf script, and its null before this.

Answer (score 1):

The session variables are being registered as global variables (references pointing to the entries in $_SESSION) by the register_globals functionality.

You need to disable register_globals in PHP.ini.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals
http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php